# Why can vectors be instantiated like arrays?

Tags: c++, instantiation

I was learning about classes in my C++ class, and I was trying to understand some of the things about common classes I've used. One of which being vector. I looked through the vector reference on Cplusplus.com, but there was one thing that I couldn't quite understand and was having trouble finding answers to it online. When making a new vector with predetermined values it's possible to do as follows:

```cpp
 vector<int> vect = {1,2,3,4,5};
 cout<< vect.at(2);
```

What's confusing to me is that I have no idea how this works, and how to possibly replicate this in a class of my own. I've looked through the constructors of the vector class but didn't see anything that seemed to relate to instantiation in this manner. Something like `vector<int> vect(6)` makes sense to me because it's just creating a vector with default size 6, but the way I mentioned above is very different from what I've seen and learned thus far.

So my questions are: How can a vector be instantiated this way, and what might a constructor for this look like?

Comment: It's a constructor accepting a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as argument

Comment: Nitpicking: the right word is "initialized" or "constructed". "Instantiated" means something else.

Comment: The method of initialisation you describe was not valid before C++11.   C++11 introduced a new initialisation syntax for C++ classes, a templated `std::initialization_list` which is a lightweight aid to help that work, and modified definitions of standard container classes (like `std::vector`) by adding constructors that accept an `initializer_list`.  So `std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3,4,5};` constructs a `std::initializer_list<int>` from  `{1,2,3,4,5}`, passes it to a constructor of `std::vector<int>` that accepts a `std::initializer_list<int>`, and that constructor initialises `vect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses an [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Just like `"string"` forms a string, `{element1, element2, ...}` forms an initializer list that can be converted to a vector, or another datatype.

For example, we could construct an array manually doing the following:

```
int w[4];
auto x = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //type is std::initializer_list

int count = 0;
for(auto i : x){
    w[count] = i;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: The handling of string literals (a string literal is represented as a statically allocated array of `char`) has no relationship to `std::initializer_list`.   Also, `initializer_list` is an (implementation-defined) templated class, not a type in its own right.